# GraphServiceClient UpdateAsync() throwing error Resource '' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using below code to update `custom extension claim attribute` but it is not working.

`GraphServiceClient UpdateAsync()` method throwing error

```
  var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
            {
               requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", graphapitoken);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }));

var  dictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
            dictionary ["extension_clientid_moviename"] = "SampleValue";

 await graphServiceClient.Users["abcdxyz@hotmail.com"] // here I'm getting error 
                .Request()
                .UpdateAsync(new User()
                {
                    AdditionalData = dictionary
                });
```

**Error:**

```
Code: Request_ResourceNotFound\r\nMessage: Resource 'abcdxyz@hotmail.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

**Update 1:**

I have created extensions following below article.

https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-ad-custom-attributes-and-optional-claims-from-an-asp-dot-net-application/

I have used Powershell commands to create `extensions`.

`extension_clientid_moviename` is the extension name.

Answer (score 0):

For guest users, you can not use their email to request a user, you should use their **Object ID** instead.

[image]

Also, you can add custom data to resources using [extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview).

**Update:**

You need `User.ReadWrite.All permission`.

[image]

Go to Azure portal->App registrations->your application->API permissions to check if you have added the permission and granted admin consent.

Comment: I have already created extension following article given in update 1 of question.Kindly let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: After using  Object id as graphServiceClient.Users["ggft679-98795-4491-y770-8de77-0mjhb-5878"] I'm getting error as  "Code: Authorization_RequestDenied\r\nMessage: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"

Comment: I have tried as per suggestions. But still I'm getting same Insufficient privileges error.I have added all permissions specified by you for graph api in azure ad application but still facing issue.

Comment: @John Did you grant admin consent?